# Loadrunner Regular Expression

Tags: regex, pcre, loadrunner

I am trying to fetch the value from a dynamic boundary. source code and snippet given below.

```
name="pvUnitPriceInclTax242" type="text" value="30.0000"

web_reg_save_param_ex("ParamName=pvUnitPriceInclTaxValue",
"RegExp=name=\"pvUnitPriceInclTax[0-9]+\" type=\"text\" value=\"([0-9]+\.[0-9]+)\"",
LAST);
```

I have checked above regular expression [here](https://regex101.com/) and its working fine. But it gives following error while running in Loadrunner.

```
The "RegExp=name="pvUnitPriceInclTax[0-9]+" type="text" value="([0-9]+.[0-9]+)"" argument (number 2) is unrecognized or misplaced
```

since Loadrunner uses PCRE, i have no idea why its happening.  Somebody please help me to solve this.

Comment: Doc says *In release 11.00, the /RE qualifier was supported. This support is discontinued because fuller regular expression functionality is now provided by `web_reg_save_param_regexp`.*

Comment: Thanks Revo.. I have changed the function, but now its giving boundary error message. Let me correct it.